# SqlConnection.OpenAsync issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, sqlconnection

I am faced with a peculiar async problem which I can reproduce easily but cannot understand.

**My Current Setup**

I have a WCF Service which exposes two API's - API1 and API2. Both the service contracts are synchronous. API1, looks up a dictionary in memory, then creates a task using Task.Factory.StartNew to create a new task which fetches data from a SQL server, compares it with the data from the dictionary and writes some logs. In case the SQl Server has connectivity issues, this re-tries SqlConnection.OpenAsync 3 more times. Note that the API call itself returns as soon as it has the data from the dictionary (does not wait for SQl operation to complete)

API2 is much simpler, it just calls a stored procedure on SQL server, gets the data and returns.

The code to open connection is as follows:

```
public static int OpenSqlConn(SqlConnection connection)
{
    return OpenSqlConn(connection).Result;
}        

public async static Task<int> OpenSqlConnAsync(SqlConnection connection)
{
    return await OpenConnAsync(connection);
}

private static async Task<int> OpenConnAsync(SqlConnection connection)
{                    
    int retryCounter = 0;

    TimeSpan? waitTime = null;

    while (true)
    {
        if (waitTime.HasValue)
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitTime.Value).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        try
        {                
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            break;
        }               
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (retryCounter >= 3)
            {                        
                SafeCloseConnection(connection);
                return retryCounter;                    
            }                   

            retryCounter++;                                        
            waitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
        }
    }
    return retryCounter;        
}
```

The API1 code looks like below:

```
public API1Response API1 (API1Request request) 
{
    // look up in memory dictionary for the request
    API1Response response = getDataFromDictionary(request);

    // create a task to get some data from DB       
    Action action = () =>
    {
        GetDataFromDb(request);
    }   
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // this is called immediately even if DB is not available and above task is retrying.
    return API1Response;
}

public void GetDataFromDb(API1Request request) 
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) 
    {
        OpenSqlConn(connection);
        /// hangs for long even if db is available

        ReadDataFromDb(connection);
    }
}

public API2Response API2(API2REquest request)
{
    return GetDataFromDbForAPI2(request)
}

public API2Response GetDataFromDbForAPI2(API2Request request) 
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) 
    {
        OpenSqlConn(connection); /// hangs for long even if db is available

        ReadDataFromDb(connection);
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

The service runs into the following problem when the SQL Server is unavailable even for short periods of time, and some client makes just 100 calls to API1:

1. When my  SQL server has connectivity issues, and I get  around 100 calls of API1, even though API1 returns to the caller, it has created 100 tasks that will try to open a connection to the bad DB. Each of those tasks hangs in a retry look for some time (which is expected). In my experiments, I can simulate a DB unavailability by using a bad connection string for API1.
2. Now let's say the DB is back up again and a call to API2 is made to the service. What I find is that when API2 call reaches the OpenAsync portion above, it hangs. *Just hangs* :(

Some observations
1. When I look at the 'Parallel Stacks' from Visual Studio, I find that there are 100 threads with the API1 stack doing the following stack :

```
 ManualResetEvenSlim.Wait()
 Task.SpinThenBlockingWait
 Task.InternalWait();
 Task<>.GetREsultCore
 OpenConn()
```

2. There is 1 thread with the API2 stack, which again is in a similar stack as above.
3. **However, if I replace `SqlConnection.OpenAsync` with `SqlConnection.Open()`, API2 call returns immediately.**

**Need Help**

What I would like to understand is why does the API2, which can open a DB connection (because DB is available at that time), also hang on OpenAsync. Is there any obvious synchronization issue that I am seeing? When i change SqlConnection.OpenAsync() to SqlConnection.Open() why does the behavior change?

Comment: If you have to add retry/delays to `connection.OpenAsync()` like that, you have bigger problems. I'd fix the issues requiring that first.

Comment: You might be running into a deadlock because you use the blocking call to `Task.Result` in `OpenSqlConn`. Don't mix async code with `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait` or any of the other way to block execution.

Comment: I have a question for you.  How does the OpenAsync() method report a failure?

Comment: @jdweng - OpenAsync ends up throwing a timeout exception

Comment: @mxmissile - you mentioned that if you have to add retry/delays to connection.OpenAsync() you have bigger problems. Can you explain a bit more. I know there is some problem in there, but not sure what. Hence my question on SO :)

Comment: That is why OpenAsycn ends up hanging up.  The only reporting mechanism OpenAsycn has is a timeout.  The Open() method doesn't have a timeout and reports the issue quickly.